# IWebBrowser2 Controlling visibility

Tags: winapi, iwebbrowser2

I create hidden IWebBrowser2 object and it work's fine but after few seconds I want to
change visibility to true and my application crashes.

```
pBrowser2->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Need more code than this.  A stack trace might be nice, too.

Comment: "Crashes" always needs to come with details such as call stack at crash position.

Comment: All backtrace from Dev C++
http://pastebin.com/E10bftuT
And Code
http://pastebin.com/zC3zvCmy

Comment: -1 Please don't ask questions about code that is not in the question. We need information in questions and not in off site links given in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `pBrowser2` after releasing it.

You have:

```
pBrowser2->Release();  // pBrowser NOW INVALID!!!
srand( time( NULL ) );
//Sleep( ( std::rand() % 5000 ) + 5000 );
if(std::rand() % 100 <= chance ){
    pBrowser2->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);  // instant crash here!
}
```

Move the call to Release() after you're done using it, or use a [COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx) [smart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) pointer so you don't have to manage it yourself.  Simplest fix:

```
srand( time( NULL ) );
//Sleep( ( std::rand() % 5000 ) + 5000 );
if(std::rand() % 100 <= chance ){
    pBrowser2->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);  // works
}
pBrowser2->Release();  // pBrowser NOW INVALID!!!
```